# Ionic add icon to swipe able top menu

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble adding icons to my swipe able menu. What is showing is {object object} how do I add an icon through typescript?

[image]

*home.html*

```
<ion-segment  class="SwipedTabs-tabs"  >
    <ion-segment-button *ngFor='let tab of tabs ; let i = index ' value="IngoreMe" (click)="selectTab(i)"
    [ngClass]='{ "SwipedTabs-activeTab" : ( this.SwipedTabsSlider  && ( this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex() === i || (  tabs.length -1 === i&& this.SwipedTabsSlider.isEnd()))) }' >
        {{tab}}
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

*home.ts*

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  this.tabs=[{'name':'people' },"page2"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use super tabs module its quick and easy to get working and its exactly what you are looking for.